# How to include the file name page number and number of pages when exporting an org mode document toa latex document

Tags: emacs, org-mode, pdflatex

I would like to include the file name, page number and number of pages when exporting an org mode file to a latex document.

I tried adding latex code snippets into the org mode document.

```
#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex
\cfoot{Seite: \thepage~ von~ \pageref{LastPage} ~ (\currfilename)}
#+END_EXPORT
```

However, that doesn't work.